# Encrypting Aurora Database via Cloudformation

Tags: encryption, amazon-aurora

I am trying to encrypt my Aurora Database via Cloudformation but it does not seem to work.

Under the Metadata tag, I have added the below --

> "Metadata": {
>
> ```
>       "Encryption": true,
>
>       "MasterKey": { "Ref" : "EncryptionKeyArn"}
> ```
>
> }

Can anyone please confirm if these are the correct parameters to be added to the cloudformation template?

When I open the database instance from AWS Console, it mentions ---

Encryption details

Encryption enabled

No

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Encryption by using the StorageEncrypted property and KMSKeyId property in DB cluster. Please go through this Documentation for DB Cluster:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-storageencrypted

Please go through this Documentation for DB Instance:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-storageencrypted